# How can I put my all asset(Html, JS, CSS, node.JS) into the react?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I do my web project and I want to do a react for make my website better but I don't know how to put all the asset that I made into the react.

Comment: I think you first need to learn react for that purpose. If you knew react a little bit, you wouldn't ask this.

Comment: public directory

Answer (score 0):

Start reading the official docs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html